# Getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' when robot framework testcases are run in command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, robotframework, decode

Whenever I am trying to run testcases in Robot framework through cmd, i am getting the below error:

`Parsing <filename with path> failed UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 31: invalid start byte`

The above error thrown for some files and below error for some files

`Parsing <filename with path> failed UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 47: invalid start byte`

And then my test fails saying there is no such tag in the suite I am referring to, but I have the tag in my file.

Initally I thought it was because of some setting in the editor(STS) I am using and changed the settings under Window-> preferences -> General -> Workspace -> text file encoding option to 'Other' and selected utf-8, gave workspace rebuild, restarted the STS, but still no luck.

Been searching for a solution since weeks. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: From the error it is not clear which line and which character. Identify the files from where this error is. Then remove 1 by 1 Testcases and put in other file and execute them.When you will get particular intended piece of code which has this error check it line by line if you see any special character. Other way to detect special character is open the file in vim editor. Also there may be possibility that code is copied from somewhere else, remove that copied code.

Comment: @Dev Your Answer helped. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that :) Happy to help! Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking each and every Testcases by removing and adding them in new file and also by removing all the special characters used in keyword definition as well in testcase definition in the robot files resolved the issue